# Limit of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(kx)}{kx}$

Tags: limits, summation

The sum
$$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(kx)}{kx}$$ 
can be written in a closed form:
$$S(x)=\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}i\left(\ln(1-\exp(ix)\right)-\ln\left(1-\exp(-ix)\right)\right)$$
I am in trouble in calculating the limit:
$$S_0=\lim_{x\to\infty}S(x)$$
Transforming the $S(x)$ in trigonometric functions I get:
$$S(x)=-\frac{1}{2x}\arctan\left(-\sin(x),1-\cos(x)\right)+\frac{1}{2x}\arctan(\sin(x),1-\cos(x))$$
but this doesn't help me to evaluate $S_0$.
I would like to have some suggestion useful to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you convinced that it converges?  Then it has to converge to $0$ since $S(x)=0$ for arbitrarily large $x$ by taking $x=n\cdot \pi$.

Comment: @Callus: obviously for $x=n\pi$ it converges, but I am not sure it converges for $x\neq n\pi$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general let us assume the series $$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}$$
for $0<x<2\pi$
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S_n(x)&=&\int_0^x \sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kt) \;\mathrm dt=-\frac{x}{2}+\int_0^x \frac{\sin\left((2n+1)\frac{t}{2}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\;\mathrm dt=\\
&=&-\frac{x}{2}+\int_0^x \frac{\sin\left((2n+1)\frac{t}{2}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\;\mathrm dt\pm \int_0^x \frac{\sin\left((2n+1)\frac{t}{2}\right)}{t}\;\mathrm dt=\\
&=&-\frac{x}{2}+\underbrace{\int_0^x \left[\frac{1}{2\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}-\frac{1}{t}\right]\sin\left((2n+1)\frac{t}{2}\right)\;\mathrm dt}_{S_{1n}(x)}+\underbrace{\int_0^x \frac{\sin\left((2n+1)\frac{t}{2}\right)}{t}\;\mathrm dt}_{S_{2n}(x)}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
According to [the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-LebesgueLemma.html) $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{1n}(x)=0$

Making substitution $u=(2n+1)\frac{t}{2}$ in $S_{2n}(x)$ will lead to
$$S_{2n}=\int_0^{(2n+1)\frac{x}{2}}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}\mathrm du$$
And $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{n}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$.

So you sum will be $$S(x)=\frac{\pi-x}{2x}$$
Will this help you to find $S_0$?

Comment: Some care is needed.  In $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$$ the left-hand side has period $2\pi$, so the restriction $0<x<2\pi$ is important.

Comment: @GEdgar it is in the very beginning.

Comment: @GEdgar: Ok. Thanks

Comment: @GEdgar: So is $S_0=-\infty$?

Comment: No, try again..

Comment: Note: $S(x)$ itself is not periodic.

Comment: @GEdgar thanks, I was a bit hasty.